# USRP N310 frequency range

Tags: sdr

[USRP N310](https://www.ettus.com/all-products/usrp-n310/) uses  [AD9371](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9371.pdf) RF transceiver but it has more  wider frequency range. The AD9371 tunable range is from 300 MHz to 6000 MHz, but the N310 with 10 MHz to 6 GHz extended frequency range. Why?

Here is the schematic of N310: [Schematic](https://kb.ettus.com/images/9/9d/USRP_N310_N300_DB_Schematic.pdf)

Comment: Is your question why they decided to increase the frequency range, or how they did it?  You'd have to ask Ettus why they wanted to cover that specific frequency band.

As to how they did it, on the first page of the schematic, there is a mixer stage on both RX2 and TX2. Those two paths are used to mix frequencies between 10 MHz and 300 MHz to a frequency that's compatible with the AD9371